# Button to copy specific data from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

`Workbook1` is where all of my data is located.

`Workbook2` is where I want to copy my data.

I would like a button to do the following:

 - Open workbook2

 - Copy data cells(listed) from workbook1: 
C3,S3,P3,J22,L22,J21,L21,C14,C15,C16,C17,C18,C19,C20,C21

 - Find next empty row in workbook2

 - Paste the data into workbook2 - horizontally. So C3 (from workbook1) data will paste into B4 (from workbook2), and S3 will paste into C4, etc.

This might be a long shot, but is there a way to have the column A display the date the data was transferred for that specific row?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Let me know if you need further explanation.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim wbData As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Dim C As Long
Dim ar As Range
Dim cl As Range

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rngDestination As Range

Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' to open the workbook
Set wbData = Workbooks.Open("A:\folder\workbook2.xlsm", True)
Set wsData = wbData.Sheets("Completed")
Set rngToCopy = wsMain.Range("C3,S3,P3,J22,L22,J21,L21,C14,C15,C16,C17,C18,C19,C20,C21")

' to get the last row in the Completed worksheet
LastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "B4").End(x1Up).Row

C = 1

For Each cl In rngToCopy
    cl.Copy
    wsData.Range("B" & C).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    C = C + 1

Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn what we'll do to help you.Short version: this isn't a code writing service so you'll have to provide your best shot at it and indicate where you're stuck, then someone will help you fix that specific issue.

Comment: sorry about that, I have added the code.

Comment: L.BAER your code is doing what you want, is pasting everything on the new book, isn't it? What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works.. It also seems like your last part of your code paste the values vertically instead of horizontally. I modified so it paste the values horizontally

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim wbData As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Dim C As Long
Dim ar As Range
Dim cl As Range

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rngDestination As Range

Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' to open the workbook
Set wbData = Workbooks.Open("A:\folder\workbook2.xlsm", True)
Set wsData = wbData.Sheets("Completed")
Set rngToCopy = wsMain.Range("C3,S3,P3,J22,L22,J21,L21,C14,C15,C16,C17,C18,C19,C20,C21")

' to get the last row in the Completed worksheet
LastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'get the last row number in Column B.


C = 1 'nth columns to go to right when codes iterate

For Each cl In rngToCopy
    cl.Copy
    wsData.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1 + C).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' Start from the last empty row (lastrow number + 1) and then start from column A (A = 1) then jump 1 step to the right in each iteration/loop.
    C = C + 1 'Increase the column number by 1
    wsData.Range("A" & LastRow + 1) = Now() ' Set date in column A for the row that was pasted
Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to help :)!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the pasting code for this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim wbData As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Dim C As Long
Dim ar As Range
Dim cl As Range

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rngDestination As Range

Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' to open the workbook
Set wbData = Workbooks.Open("A:\folder\workbook2.xlsm", True)
Set wsData = wbData.Sheets("Completed")


' to get the last row in the Completed worksheet
LastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

' to paste the values
wsMain.Range("C3,S3,P3,J22,L22,J21,L21,C14,C15,C16,C17,C18,C19,C20,C21").Copy
wsData.Range("B" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'to get the Date and time when it was pasted
wsData.Range("A" & Lastrow) = Now()

End Sub
```

Comment: Damian, I keep getting the Run-Time error '1004': when I debug it highlights ... LastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "B4").End(x1Up).Row + 1

Comment: Try like this... I saw now you used x1up instead xlUp

Comment: I made the change, I got the same error for the same code

Comment: LastRow = wsData.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row + 1 try this, it will get the last row if there are no blank cells in between